# how to create some breakpoints in a js script to debug it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two pages with a similar content and both of them use the bootstrap tab feature to display data. 
These tabs are steps of a wizard so I don't want to have users to navigate away of the current tab by clicking on another. So I have written this small js to check if the tab has the "disabled" class that will prevent going to that tab.

On one page it works fine, on the other it doesn't identify the "disabled" class and so on click on the title the new tab is displayed. **I am looking for suggestion on how to create some breakpoints in my js code and understand where it breaks.** This because there is obviously something in my code that is not working but I cannot find what. The console log statement inside the if block is never executed.

```
<div class="wizard-inner">
    <div class="connecting-line colored-line"></div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="navigator">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Crea il tuo form">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Scegli i campi da visualizzare">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Anteprima">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Scegli gli utenti">
                    <span class="round-tab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Controlli del wizard */
    //TODO verifica perchè posso andare avanti cliccando sugli elementi anche se sono disabilitati
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();
    $('.bs-glyphicons-list > li[title]').tooltip();
    //Wizard
    //inizializzo mostrando solo il primo
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            console.log('sono qui');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: after so much time on SE I still find it really weird to just downvote a question without a single reason for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to test only the following block:

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            console.log('sono qui');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

First of all, I would try to extract `$('a[data-toggle="tab"]')` and check whether it exists:

```
const elements = $('a[data-toggle="tab"]'); // NEW
console.log(elements); // NEW
elements.on('show.bs.tab', function (e) { // NEW
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            console.log('sono qui');
            return false;
        }
});
```

Please note tha I haven't done it this way by just making a copy of the `$('a[data-toggle="tab"]')` statement because I want to be 100% sure that what I am printing to console is the same thing I am using further in the code (don't do like this code):

```
const elements = $('a[data-toggle="tab"]'); // NEW
console.log(elements); // NEW
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) { // CHANGE HERE TO VARIABLE TOO!!!
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            console.log('sono qui');
            return false;
        }
});
```

If everything is fine and you see the elements, then revert to previous code and the next step is to check whether `show.bs.tap` event is ever fired on any of those elements:

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        console.log(e); // NEW
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            console.log('sono qui');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If you do do the action and the event is printed to the console, check if has the target:

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        console.log($target); // NEW
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            console.log('sono qui');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Has the target? Check if it has the parent:

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        const parent = $target.parent() // NEW
        console.log(parent) // NEW
        if (parent.hasClass('disabled')) { // NEW
            console.log('sono qui');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Browse through the printout of `parent` in the console via dropdowns and find if it has the necessary class.

On one of those steps you will find the syntax or logical error in your code.

Good luck! :)

Comment: This method of drilling down served me really well, I hope it will help you too :)

Comment: yeah. I'm fan of it but used to it more in php than in js. Thanks for helping

Comment: Also, I suspect that `$target.parent()` might be incorrect, try `$target.parent` instead

Comment: But to check it, you need to print `$target.parent()` out to check whether it is `undefined`

Comment: the same code works well in another page. I found out that console.log(e); is where I don't get anything and I need to drill down on that. Why it is not triggered while the tabs are correctly displayed